# How to rename fields returned from Laravel's Query Builder withCount (aka $asColumn)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a single model and I am trying to chain on multiple withCounts with different relations. Here is an example:

```
    return MyModel::query()
        ->withCount(array('users'=>function($query){
            $query->where('enabled', '=', 1);
        }))
        ->withCount(array('users'=>function($query){
            $query->where('phone', '=', "123-4567");
        }))
        ->get();
```

This doesn't work because Laravel automatically returns a snake_case field name in my results called "users_count", and basically this means the enabled section of the query is overwritten with the phone section.

I've peeked into the Builder.php class a bit and noticed that $asColumn is the name being returned: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/67b821dde62e64f94aa7d99f1806ecf03ea323e5, which like mentioned is just a snake_case of the relation's $name + '_count'.

Is there any way to make a custom $asColumn without using a raw query so that I can get both results? I basically want my results to be enabled_users_count and phone_users_count, or something similar. I'd also prefer not to have to do 2 different queries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This functionality is available as of Laravel 5.3.7, released on 2016-09-08.

Assuming you are on 5.3.7 or later, you just need to add `as new_name` to the relationship string in the `withCount` method, and it will name the count field as `new_name_count`. So, your code would look like:

```
return MyModel::query()
    ->withCount(array('users as enabled_users'=>function($query){
        $query->where('enabled', '=', 1);
    }))
    ->withCount(array('users as phone_users'=>function($query){
        $query->where('phone', '=', "123-4567");
    }))
    ->get();
```

This code will generate an `enabled_users_count` field and a `phone_users_count` field.

If you are not on this version, and cannot upgrade, you will need to go the route of defining a new relationship, as mentioned by @RossWilson.

---

#### Laravel >= 5.5

Starting in Laravel 5.5, the `_count` suffix will not be appended if you specify a column alias. So, starting in 5.5, the above example would generate `enabled_users` and `phone_users` fields, instead of `enabled_users_count` and `phone_users_count` fields.

The `_count` suffix is still automatically appended if there is no alias specified, though. So, `withCount('users')` would still generate a `users_count` field.

Comment: I think this answer and @Ross Wilson are both correct, but this answer seems a bit more clean since it's built into the library. Unfortunately for me I'm on an older version of Laravel so I will have to use his.

Comment: I know this is from a long time ago but is this naming convention still followed in Laravel 6.x? I ask because it seems it changed to be exactly what you specified. So without the suffix '_count'.

Comment: @Daniel No. It looks like it was changed slightly in 5.5. Starting with 5.5.0, if you specify the field name alias, it won't append "_count" to the name you specify. If you don't specify an alias, it will append "_count" to the field name. So, starting in 5.5.0, if you say `withCount('users as enabled_users')`, the field name will be `enabled_users`, not `enabled_users_count`. However, `withCount('users')` will still return `users_count`.

Answer (score 7):

The only way that I know of would to define different relationships for those conditions and then use the `withCount` with those e.g.

```
public function enableUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class) //Or whatever the relationship is
        ->where('enabled', '=', 1);
}
```

then:

```
MyModel::withCount('enabledUsers', 'phoneUsers')->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I never knew you could add clauses like ->where() directly to the relation. Good Answer!